# Connect To Google Cloud Sql From Metabase cloud

Tags: google-cloud-sql, metabase

I have a google cloud Sql Instance.I have just Created a metabase account on metabase website cloud account and want to add datasource. but when i enter a credential of my database could not connect. it showes that i have to add metabase to google cloud connection network. i searched the documentation of metabase but there was not any info of ip address of cloud service to add in google what is the metabase ip address to fit in this form?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated [here](https://discourse.metabase.com/t/ip-to-whitelist-for-metabase-cloud-instances/11614/3) you should whitelist the following IP addresses for Metabase Cloud instances in your Cloud SQL configuration:

```
18.207.81.126
3.211.20.157
50.17.234.169
```